# Laravel 5.4 $request->get trims whitespace in input

Tags: forms, laravel, whitespace

Laravel is trimming whitespace at the beginning of the string.
Example:

`"     this is a test"`

Is returning

`This is a test`

I use Laravels `$request->get('name')`

When i use `$_POST` in the laravel application it is working fine.

Does somebody know how i can achive this with `$request->get()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In laravel 5.4, Taylor added the `TrimStrings` middleware to default middleware group. So you can remove the `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class` from the `Http\Kernel.php`.

Comment: Thanks Pankit, i uncommented `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class` and it works now

Comment: I meet the same error and solve it by your solution but I wonder what is the purpose of Laravel Author when auto trim the params? is there any case it will cause an exception if we remove it?

Comment: ... there is an except in App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings ... cool.

Comment: OMG why?? This caused me so much frustration and literal hours of debugging. I am using a third party plugin on the frontend that does syntax highlighting for code blocks and it passes objects like `[{"text": "function"}, { "text" : " " }, { "text": "myFunction" } ... ]` which was being collapsed and causing the text to be stuck together without the spaces.